# SQL How to INNER JOIN multiple values with similar field names

Tags: sql, join

I have a table named **players**

```
p_id | first    | last
========================
1    | Michael  | Jordan
2    | Charles  | Barkley
3    | Kobe     | Bryant
4    | Allen    | Iverson
5    | Kevin    | Garnett
```

Then I have a table named **users**

```
u_id | user | player_1 | player_2 | player_3
============================================
1    | John | 1        | 2        | 5
2    | Jane | 3        | 4        | 5
3    | Jim  | 2        | 3        | 4
```

Through a form on the website, users pick their players (fields: player_1, player_2, player_3 correspond to the id's from the **players** table

I'm trying to run an INNER JOIN where I print the **user** from the **users** table and their player selections (first, last)

So far I have this

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN players p1 ON player_1 = p1.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p2 ON player_2 = p2.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p3 ON player_3 = p3.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p4 ON player_4 = p4.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p5 ON player_5 = p5.player_id                
ORDER BY data";
```

When I run

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_users))
{
$player_1_first = $row['player_name'];      
$player_1_last = $row['player_last'];

echo $player_1_first." ".$player_2_last;
}
```

I only get the very last selection of the user.

**My questsion:**
How do I get to do correctly what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: On a side note, you might want to read up on database normalization.  I see potential problems with your `users` table.

Comment: you should improve your schema and have a `users_players` table with `userid | playerid` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
SELECT users.*, p1.player_id AS player1_id, p2.player_id AS player2_id, p3.player_id AS player3_id, p4.player_id AS player4_id, p5.player_id AS player5_id FROM users 
INNER JOIN players p1 ON player_1 = p1.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p2 ON player_2 = p2.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p3 ON player_3 = p3.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p4 ON player_4 = p4.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p5 ON player_5 = p5.player_id                
ORDER BY data";
```

In your PHP code you would of course select the fields by their name as they are 'renamed' in the Select clause.

But you should also revise your database schema, since a good schema wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are after (you don't really say) you need to change the select to request the output you want
so

```
SELECT users.FieldsYouWant, 
p1.first as p1first, p1.last as p1last, 
p2.first as p2first, p2.last as p2last,
p3.first as p3first, p3.last as p3last, 
p4.first as p4first, p4.last as p4last, 
p5.first as p5first, p5.last as p5last 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN players p1 ON player_1 = p1.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p2 ON player_2 = p2.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p3 ON player_3 = p3.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p4 ON player_4 = p4.player_id                
INNER JOIN players p5 ON player_5 = p5.player_id                
ORDER BY data";
```

Then in your output read all 5 names in a single line
Note that if the user doesn't have 5 players selected you will get nothing